# How to setup paypal payment method and test it , if its working properly in magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I want to setup payment methods ,
Starting with paypal , how can i configure it and make into work ?

Answer (score 0):

Your are follow two links and helpful for enable paypal payment method and test:-

How to cerate the paypal account :-

**https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/live/paypal-onboarding.html**

How to enable the paypal method with test :-

**https://magenticians.com/magento-2-paypal-payment-gateway-integration/**

How to enable the test paypal method check screenshort :-

[image]

Comment: Hello helpful this answer so please accept because use to the other community